# How to get jdb-like features (setting breakpoints or displaying vars) in sbt or REPL for Scala?

Tags: scala, debugging, sbt, read-eval-print-loop

Rather than opening up jdb is there a way to get similar functionality within the repl or sbt session?

The features I am seeking:

- ability to define breakpoints:

  - :bp mySource.scala:79  // stop at line 79 mySource.scala
  - :bp org.mycompany.MyClass:14  // stop at line 14 of myClass (no idea if anyone supports such a thing..)
- print out vars

  - :p myList
- evaluate expressions including case statements and bonus points for closures

Comment: What would that buy you in sbt? Why do you think sbt would benefit from the feature or users who use sbt to use it in jdb-like manner? I'd rather think of Scala REPL to have it not sbt itself.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski   From the title - either sbt or REPL - it was not specified which one.

Comment: Sure, but your question made me wonder how it could work in sbt if it were available. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: the advantage of sbt is it already has the classpath set up.  I could envision  sbt debug. that's really convenient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't keep a good idea down -- see the thread [A non-runaway-REPL?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/Eq9p4iwAVuM/bPvfqrwOWzAJ):

> Maybe it could also use a "safe" mode where it forks a JVM. While
>   we're at it, it's time for a debug command.

I don't know if the command should be called `:forked`, `:borked`, or simply `:wtf`.

Comment: That link is for control-C handling. Did you intend to send a different link?

Comment: @javadba See clarifying edit. I also don't know if the "worksheet" in the eclipse IDE supports debug perspective. Probably "obviously not," but that would be neat.

Comment: Well your comment seems to indicate there is presently "no such luck". I guess will wait to see if your answer were the consensus. Thanks for the input in any case.